# how to select multiple items from dropdown in autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField for multiple choice field. I'm able to get dropdown populated with values and for each value i need to enter the text and select values.
If I need to select 10 values from the drop down i need to type 10 times. Is there a way to enable/allow multiple select from download so that user needn't type in the regex in search field 10 times?

```
class HostGroupModelForm( autocomplete_light.ModelForm ):
hosts=autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField('HostAutocomplete')

class HostAutocomplete( autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase ):
search_fields = [ 'hostname' ]
limit_choices = 75
choices = Host.objects.all()
```